# Mapping array values to PickerItem: "Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

New to React, following a tutorial online. Tutor initially wrote this code:

```
<Picker selectedValue={this.props.day}>
  <Picker.item label='Monday' value='Monday' />
  <Picker.item label='Tuesday' value='Tuesday' />
  <Picker.item label='Wednesday' value='Wednesday' />
  <Picker.item label='Thursday' value='Thursday' />
  <Picker.item label='Friday' value='Friday' />
  <Picker.item label='Saturday' value='Saturday' />
  <Picker.item label='Sunday' value='Sunday' />
</Picker>
```

Rendered absolutely fine.

That being said, it's ugly code. I thought it would be cleaner to map this from an array, like so:

```
renderPickerItems() {
    return ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
            'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'].map(day =>
        <Picker.item label={day} value={day} />
    );
}
```

So, I wrote that function and replaced the first block of code with just this:

```
<Picker selectedValue={this.props.day}>
  {this.renderPickerItems()}
</Picker>
```

That, however, did not work.

I received the error:

`Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined`

I tried printing the return of that method to the console and I actually got React Native objects with the correct props passed in, so I'm not sure why it fails at all.

What I'm trying to accomplish seems very trivial and I can't seem to find anyone who had similar issues.

I'm on React Native version 0.51.0.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer was that I'm just terrible at following instructions.

The correct syntax is `Picker.Item` and not `Picker.item`.